Get the number of rows returned by a query in MySQL
Is there an easy way to get the number of rows returned by a query as well as the rows themselves.  For example, in a stored procedure, I need to return rows from a query and, if no rows are being returned, I need to do additional processing.
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
IF [Number of rows] = 0 THEN
    [Do other stuff]
END IF;

The Proc still needs to return the contents of MyTable even if it doesn't have any rows.  I know this can be using two SELECT statements (a COUNT() to get the number of rows and a second to get the rows), but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with a single SELECT.

Use the ROW_COUNT() function

No, not in SQL.
The ROW_COUNT() function is for rows affected, not rows returned. It's useful for DML like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, but it returns -1 for a SELECT query.
Some client interfaces do have a rows-returned function, but this works only after the client has fetched a result set. A client doesn't know how many rows will be returned until it fetches them.
As you wrote, you can write a SELECT COUNT(*)... query first. That's what I'd do.

Thanks.  I was hoping that I wouldn't need to run the same query twice, but it looks like I have no choice.

You could find this out with a cursor. You run the select query that you have and do a single fetch (see https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/sql-cursor-in-stored-procedures/) and if there was an element in this cursor, then it is not empty and proceed in that manner, otherwise it is empty.

This is an interesting solution.  Would it impact the requirement that the query results are returned from the SP?

@FrankSchnabel I have not tested it. But if so, then you could fetch all and have a flag turned "green" if there are elements.
